# My php CURL log in script not succeeding in asp page

Tags: php, asp.net, curl, single-sign-on, siteminder

I want to log into a website using php CURL script but it is getting redirected into a loop on the last step.

I have used Fiddler to capture the HTTP request and responses while using Firefox and Internet Explorer.  I recreated the steps in my script.

The site has several steps involving 302 redirects, JavaScript setting cookies just before form submission, and location redirection as well.

All of this has gone well until the last step. The website loads the following.

```
    HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Connection: Keep-Alive
Server: Microsoft-IIS/5.0
Date: Sun, 12 Aug 2012 15:51:55 GMT
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Set-Cookie: SMSESSION=*omitted by me*; path=/; domain=website.com
Content-Length: 511
Content-Type: text/html
Set-Cookie: BIGipServerPortal_80_Green=3741601290.20480.0000; expires=Sun, 12-Aug-2012 17:51:57 GMT; path=/
Cache-Control: private
X-PvInfo: [S10201.C29051.A26868.RA0.G7175.U147B7189].[OT/html.OG/pages]
Vary: Accept-Encoding, User-Agent
Content-Encoding: gzip



<!--START:INC\common\include.asp-->
<!--START:INC\common\errorfns.asp-->

<!--END:INC\common\errorfns.asp--><!--START:INC\common\newconstant.asp-->

<!--END:INC\common\newconstant.asp--><!--START:INC\common\securityfns.asp-->

<!--END:INC\common\securityfns.asp--><!--START:INC\common\newptintllocales.asp-->

<!--END:INC\common\newptintllocales.asp-->

<!--START:INC\common\newptintl.asp-->


<!--END:INC\common\newptintl.asp-->

<!--START:INC\common\newutility.asp-->

<!--END:INC\common\newutility.asp-->
<!--END:INC\common\include.asp--><!--START:INC\sso\vendors\ActiveDirectoryServer.asp-->


<!--END:INC\sso\vendors\ActiveDirectoryServer.asp--><!--START:INC\sso\vendors\netegrity.asp-->


<!--END:INC\sso\vendors\netegrity.asp--><!--START:INC\sso\vendors\oblix.asp-->


<!--END:INC\sso\vendors\oblix.asp-->
<!--START:INC\sso\vendors\securant.asp-->


<!--END:INC\sso\vendors\securant.asp--><!--START:INC\sso\vendors\Tivoli.asp-->


<!--END:INC\sso\vendors\Tivoli.asp-->
<!--START:INC\sso\vendors\customsso.asp-->


<!--END:INC\sso\vendors\customsso.asp-->
<!--START:INC\sso\ssoutility.asp-->


<!--END:INC\sso\ssoutility.asp-->
<!--START:INC\sso\sso.asp-->


    <HTML>
        <BODY onload="javascript:void(document.dologin.submit())">
            <FORM ACTION="../admin/dologin.asp" METHOD="POST" NAME="dologin">
                <INPUT TYPE="HIDDEN" NAME="RedirectURL" VALUE="">
                <INPUT TYPE="HIDDEN" NAME="ssoMode" VALUE="1">
            </FORM>
        </BODY>
    </HTML>



<!--END:INC\sso\sso.asp-->
```

When Firefox submits this form it is redirected to the proper content.  But my CURL script is redirected to this same page but the form input now has the
 RedirectURL value set as `admin/login.asp?Mode=1`

```
<HTML>
        <BODY onload="javascript:void(document.dologin.submit())">
            <FORM ACTION="../admin/dologin.asp" METHOD="POST" NAME="dologin">
                <INPUT TYPE="HIDDEN" NAME="RedirectURL" VALUE="/admin/login.asp?Mode=1">
                <INPUT TYPE="HIDDEN" NAME="ssoMode" VALUE="1">
            </FORM>
        </BODY>
    </HTML>
```

I have used Fiddler to copy and paste the execution of the browser and CURL and compared them line by line.  Both are sending the same information, I am not missing any cookies.

The only difference's I can see is the order of the Headers sent and the order of the COOKIES sent.

I have adjusted my CURL to send the same headers as firefox but I can't get the order the same.

FireFox Header

```
GET https://www.website.aa.com/ HTTP/1.1 
Host: www.website.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:14.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/14.0.1 
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5 
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: keep-alive
```

CURL HEADER

```
GET /login/SMLogin.jsp? HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:14.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/14.0.1
Host: www.website.com
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5
Connection: keep-alive
```

The biggest difference is CURL sends the User-Agent before HOST: and the Accept-Encoding: is in a different order.
I've tried to rearrange things by setting CURL options in different orders but can't seem to get the same order as Firefox.

Here are my CURL options.(I've omitted steps that choose GET or POST and create querystring)

```
//process the header
$headerArray = array();
$headerArray[] = 'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8';
$headerArray[] = 'Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5'; 
$headerArray[] = 'Connection: keep-alive';
    if($ref != ""){
    $headerArray[] = 'Referer: ' . $ref;
    }
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headerArray) ;

// set up the cURL resource
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, CURL_TIMEOUT);    // Timeout
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, WEBBOT_NAME);   // Webbot name
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "gzip, deflate");   

// SSL SECTION
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, getcwd() . '\cert\ca-bundle.crt');

// Cookie management.
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, COOKIE_FILE);   
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, COOKIE_FILE);


curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, TRUE);    
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);     
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $target);
```

The other difference is the order in which cookies are being sent.  Since I'm letting CURL
handle the cookie managment, I can't control the order.  Unless I manage the cookies myself and set them with the `CURLOPT_COOKIE` option but that seems like a pain.

So is it most likely the order of the headers and/or the order of the COOKIES being sent is telling the server my script is not a real browser and redirecting me away from the protected content? If so how can I change this?  Or am I missing something else?

**EDIT**  This is for @MARC_B comment "javascript setting cookies" says it all.

Yes I understand CURL does not do javascript.  I have reviewed the javascript and have replicated the actions in the script.  On one page after submitting the login form, javascript validates the username and then sets a cookie.

```
if (validate) {
        document.cookie = "loggedIn=yes";
        document.Login.submit();
}
```

So after retrieving the page, the script writes the above cookie to the cookie file.

```
$handle = fopen("cookies.txt", "a");

$cookie = "website.com  FALSE   /login/ FALSE   0   loggedIn    yes";

fwrite($handle, $cookie);
fclose($handle);
```

The other javascript actions just submit the forms automatically which only takes execution of the CURL to replicate.

I have made progress.  After quite a long day of googling, I found one of the webforms is part of the [CA Siteminder](http://support.ca.com/cadocs/0/CA%20SiteMinder%20r12%205-ENU/Bookshelf_Files/HTML/idocs/index.htm?toc.htm?1915257.html?zoom_highlight=firefox) software to protect resources. The link documentation shows the form collects the browser being used.  The agentname is encrypted (not sure why that is needed) in the form.  I couldn't find any documentation as to why the browser is important.  I wonder if the encryted string is created from the agentname header or by using a combination and order of the header names that are sent.

I was beginning the script with no cookies set.  After a second review line by line of response headers, I focused on 2 particular cookies. Each run of the script 1 of the  2 cookies was never being set in the response.  But if would be different each time.

I decided to have the cookie file setup with all the cookies that showed up when logging in with Firefox.  This time the script continued on to a new page after one loop through the page mentioned above.  The new page has JavaScript that is detecting the browser type and settings.  It will take a while to analyze the page.

**So the answer seems to be I was missing 1 of several necessary cookies.**

If anyone can shed some light on the Siteminder ecosystem and typical log in scripts of asp, I would like to hear about it.

Comment: "javascript setting cookies" says it all. curl just does HTTP. it doesn't execute any JS in the retrieved html, and neither will PHP.

Comment: There is only one cookie set and I created the cookie in the script and saved it inside the cookiefile. It is submitted correctly. That is not the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try to debug the js functions and emu them.If you can't,then curl can't help you.